# Robot Framework Selenium Library - Don't wait for result from submitting form

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm new to using Robot Framework/Selenium Library.

I'm trying to create a test that enters values into form fields and submits the form by clicking a button.

I only want to check if an alert is present immediately after submitting the form, then close the browser and end the test but at the moment the test is waiting the 2-3 minutes it takes for my script to finish running and the new page to be loaded.

Is there a way I can tell Selenium not to wait for the result and check for the alert immediately then close the browser after verifying if the alert is present or not? The flow of the test currently is:

```
Test Alert Present
    Open Browser And Maximize

    Select From List By Value    id=mySelect    myValue

    Click Button    id=runScript  << waits 2-3 minutes here

    Alert Should Be Present

    Close Browser
```

Thanks

Edit:

This seems to be a problem specifically when running tests with Google Chrome.
When running with Firefox, Selenium seems to wait 5 seconds before continuing with the next test instructions.

Answer (score 0):

First, get the values to understand if selenium is waiting or anything else:

```
Get Selenium Speed
Get Selenium Implicit Wait
```

Log them to console then we can decide next steps.